# Could not able to replace some terms in my final expresion

Tags: replacement

I have three equations. The third one is the sum of the first and the second. I wanted to replace some terms in the third equation but it is not happening. I don't know why

```
zbeam=-(((0. + 0.00434059 I) b1^3 Sec[(4 b1)/3] Sech[(4 b1)/3] Sin[
       4 b1] Sinh[4 b1])/(
     Sqrt[b1^4] (-2. Sin[(8 b1)/3] Sinh[(4 b1)/3]^2 + 
        2 Cosh[(8 b1)/3] Sin[(4 b1)/3]^2 Tanh[(4 b1)/3] + 
        2. Sinh[(8 b1)/
          3] (Sin[(4 b1)/3]^2 - 
           0.5 Cos[(8 b1)/3] Tan[(4 b1)/3] Tanh[(4 b1)/3]))));
    zbar=-(((0. + 1.00951*10^13 I) b2 Cot[b2])/Sqrt[b2^2]);
    zcomb = FullSimplify[(zbeam + zbar)] /. {b1 -> 
        Surd[(r*A*\[Omega]^2)/(Iyy*Y), 4], 
       b2 -> Sqrt[(\[Omega]^2*Y)/r]}
```

Comment: It works for me (Win7, Mma 12). I would only propose to exchange the places of `Simplify` and the replacement, like this: `zcomb = Simplify[(zbeam + zbar) /. rule]` where rule is just your rule `rule = {b1 -> Surd[(r*A*\[Omega]^2)/(Iyy*Y), 4], 
  b2 -> Sqrt[(\[Omega]^2*Y)/r]}`.

Comment: its not working, I tried your suggestion

Comment: I started with a fresh empty notebook before evaluating any code. I replaced your third equation with `zcomb=FullSimplify[(zbeam+zbar)]` and evaluated the notebook to see the result. I then evaluated `zcomb/.b1->Surd[(r*A*ω^2)/(Iyy*Y),4]` to see the difference. I then evaluated `zcomb/.{b1->Surd[(r*A*ω^2)/(Iyy*Y),4], b2->Sqrt[(ω^2*Y)/r]}` to see the difference. Can you reproduce exactly these steps?